# Modifying value in dataframe column based on other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe(df) with column A and B:

```
   A   B
0  'a' 50
1  'b' 25
2  'a' 30
3  'c' 200
```

I want to multiply value of column B by 100 if column A value is 'a' so my output should be:

```
   A   B
0  'a' 5000
1  'b' 25
2  'a' 3000
3  'c' 200
```

Could anyone please suggest a cleaner way to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
df['B']=np.where(df['A']=="'a'",df['B']*100,df['B'])
```

After running above code, value of dataframe will be as follows.

```
     A  B
0   'a' 5000
1   'b' 25
2   'a' 3000
3   'c' 200
```

[np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy.where) could be read for knowing about `np.where`

Answer (score 4):

I think test substrings is not necessary, only use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with compare value `a`:

```
df.loc[df['A'] == "'a'", 'B'] *= 100
#same like
#df.loc[df['A'] == "'a'", 'B'] = df.loc[df['A'] == "'a'", 'B'] * 100
print (df)
   A     B
0  a  5000
1  b    25
2  a  3000
3  c   200
```

Answer (score 0):

`df.loc[df["A"] == "a", "B"] *= 100`

or you can use `where` function if you need something else. However for this case, it will be enough.