# Modifying columns in a dataframe based off of other values in the row

Tags: python, pandas

With this data frame

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 'data' | 2 | 3 |
| 'dota' | 3 | 4 |

I would like to modify the values in columns B and C based off of the value in column A. Currently I can do it using something like

```
df['B'] = df['A'].map(lambda x: cache[x]['mapVal'])
df['C'] = df['A'].map(lambda x: cache[x]['diffMapVal'])
```

In this case the value of column B and C is reliant on the value of column A. They also require a unique key that's based off their own column (e.g. B has its own key and C has its own key).

To throw another twist into the mix, there are certain conditions where B and C should *not* be modified if `foo(val(B)) == True` where foo is a predicate and val gives the value of column B on whatever row we're on.

So essentially the task is

```
if foo(B) and foo(C) then continue
set value of B equal to cache[val(A)][keyOfB]
set value of C equal to cache[val(A)][keyOfC]
```

After looking at a few questions [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59573916/modifying-value-in-dataframe-column-based-on-other-column) question seems relevant. But I can't quite find out how to access the value of A in the dataframe given that it's being filtered by the where statement.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` to apply your logic row-wise

```
def func(row):
   if not foo(row.B):
      row['B'] = cache[row.A]['mapVal']
   if not foo(row.C):
      row['C'] = cache[row.A]['diffMapVal']
   return row 

df = df.apply(func, axis=1)
```